# MySQL INSERT IGNORE result (was the record added or not)?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net-2010

I'm using VB.NET with MySQL and would like to know if there's a way to know if an INSERT IGNORE sql has added a new record to DB or not.

Given a Table (tblA) with one column (col1) and 1 record ('foo')

```
-------
| col1 |
-------
| foo  |
-------
```

The sql `"INSERT IGNORE INTO tblA VALUES ('foo');"` would silent fail, i.e no record added

but sql `"INSERT IGNORE INTO tblA VALUES ('bar');"` would succed, inserting a new record.

So i need to be aware of the result...

suggestions?

Thx
Paulo Bueno.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a VB.NET person, but you want the equivalent of `mysql_affected_rows`. This will be 1 if the record was inserted, and zero otherwise. Additional queries aren't necessary.

Answer (score -2):

You can query for the number of rows in the table **before** and **after** the INSERT operation, and check if the results differ. If they do, the operation did insert a row.

Comment: Assuming no one else inserted anything between your insert and select count?

Comment: @Adnam: if this is done in a transaction with REPEATABLE READ isolation mode (which is the default for MySQL) then the count before and after **will** be reliable because the transaction will not see other inserts or deletes. But it sure is not an efficient way to do it.